# Column doesn't execute formula Excel/C#/EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have this excel sheet I produce right out of a C#.NET application with EPPlus and I have a formula that won't execute unless I click manually on the cell and press enter.

This is my current output (First value being F column and second being G) :

```
02:10:58    04:30:00    =F1/G1
01:50:52    04:06:00    =F2/G2
```

This is what it should look like:

```
02:10:58    04:30:00    0,485061728
01:50:52    04:06:00    0,450677507
```

The values on C# side are initialized as strings and that's probably what's causing the error :

```
string performance = "=F" + (list.Count + 2) + "/G" + (list.Count + 2)
```

Is there a workaround or another way to initialized my column in order to show directly the value to user?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Code that creates the excel file

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Informations_OF");
worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(list.ToListExport(), true);
worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
```

Comment: You are pasting the formula in as text or you are in 'Show Formulas' view mode. In the case of the former, set the column to General format and run a quick Text-to-Columns, Fixed width through it; for the latter, choose the correct view mode.

Comment: I can confirm I am not in "show formulas" mode, and yes the problem is that I am pasting the formula in as text but I can't manage to make it calculate all at once

Comment: @J.Lavoie post the code that sets the formula

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated the question but yeah that's the problem i'm running in... I don't know how to tell EPPlus that this column is formula type! I'm only passing my item list and the formula in it is a string treated as text by excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're probably setting the Value property of the cell in your C# code. Try setting the Formula property instead. Oh, and drop the leading "=" in your formula definition - the documentation for EPPlus states that you shouldn't put it in there.

**Updated with code sample**

```
var path = @"C:\Temp\EPPlus Demo.xlsx";

var fi = new FileInfo(path);
if (fi.Exists)
    fi.Delete();

using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var wb = pck.Workbook;
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Demo");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(list.ToListExport(), true);
    for (var r = 2; r <= ws.Dimension.Rows; r++)
    {
        ws.Cells[r, 8].Formula = $"F{r}/G{r}";
        // Or alternatively, using R1C1 format
        ws.Cells[r, 8].FormulaR1C1 = "RC[-2]/RC[-1]";
    }
    pck.SaveAs(fi);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way in EPPlus to tell all my column is Formula property?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: OK, LoadFromCollection() is just going to write everything as a Value, so if you have string properties in your collection items that contain formulae, they're going to be written just like any other string. You'll need to explicitly set the value of the formulae on a cell-by-cell basis after loading your data into the sheet. I've updated my answer above with some sample code.

Comment: Ok, I was only missing "for (var r = 2; r <= ws.Dimension.Rows; r++) ws.Cells[r, 8].Formula = $"F{r}/G{r}";" part but that's exactly what I needed! Thanks :)

Comment: What's the difference between R1C1 format and the other?

Comment: R1C1 format allows you to specify a RELATIVE location, whereas the "regular" format requires absolute cell co-ordinates. So, for example, RC[-2] means same row, but back 2 columns, R[2]C[2] is two columns over and two rows down. Much easier than "so I'm in column H and I need to reference whatever's six columns over..."

Comment: Small correction to your answer:  you should replace `ws.Cells[r, 8].Formula = $"F{r}/G{r}";`   by  `ws.Cells[r, 8].Formula = "F"+r+"/G"+r;` because first way isn't working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147284/discussion-between-pete-and-j-lavoie).

Comment: After discussion use his way if you're using c# 6.0 or above!